# input-group-addon in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm starting a new project and I decided to update to Bootstrap 4. Creating a form I realized that the class 'input-group-addon' was not working properly.

I don't understand why, but it works perfectly when I use bootstrap-4-alpha. Neither bootstrap.css nor bootstrap-grid.css nor bootstrap-reboot.css have any reference to this class.

Am I missing something? Have they removed it?

I don't really understand the difference between bootstrap, bootstrap-grid, and bootstrap-reboot, but that's a different question I guess.

Comment: **Read** the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 *alpha* is almost dinosaur-age old by now. But here's the answer to your question:

> We’ve dropped `.input-group-addon` and `.input-group-btn` for two new classes, `.input-group-prepend` and `.input-group-append`. You must explicitly use an append or a prepend now, simplifying much of our CSS. Within an append or prepend, place your buttons as they would exist anywhere else, but wrap text in `.input-group-text`.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#input-groups

and:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks for the answer! Anyway, I think this solution is harder to use, since you have to use 2 tags for it with 2 clases [ "input-group-append" + "input-group-text"]. Also, there is are 2 different classes: 'prepend' when it goes first and 'append' when it goes at the end.